# Jump to an item in Listbox

Tags: vba, listbox

One question, it is possible to jump somehow to a certain index in a specif listbox as in the image below?

[image]

I already tried the following code

```
Listbox.ListIndex = index
```

But it drives me to the error ***You've used the ListIndex property incorrectly***

One property of my list that might be important to mention.

Row source type : Table/Query

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to do again? Jump to specific index how? By typing in something in the textbox and matching it against the items in the list?

Comment: Exactly @mehow , but i don't know whether it is possible to do it with Row source type as Table/Query.

Comment: is my answer what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ListBox.Selected(index) = True`. If it is a multiselect listbox, you also need to loop through the other elements and unselect them in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Create a standard module with the code

```
Sub Main()
    UserForm1.Show
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Insert a userform and visually do something like

[image]

Go into the userform code and add

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim v As Long
    For v = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If TextBox1 = ListBox1.List(v) Then
            ListBox1.Selected(v) = True
        End If
    Next v

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With ListBox1
        .AddItem ("text1")
        .AddItem ("text2")
        .AddItem ("text3")
    End With

End Sub
```

Run `Main` Macro

Type in the box : `text2`

The `text2` will be selected in the list

[image]